# How to implement inline autocomplete email edittext in android?

Tags: android

I want to use inline auto complete functionality same as google search for my android app. when I start typing in email editText and after '@' it should give me domain suggestion based on entered first letter of domain name.

Comment: May you dont know about `AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView allows users to get suggestions from DropdownList but I want inline suggestions for domain names.

Comment: With inline autocomplete edittext (like in gmail), it's possible to suggest only one item, instead using autocomplete dropdown, we can give multiple suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try `onKeyDown()` method. 
And when user entered '@', you can show a `PopupWindow` which is a ListView with domain you set to it. 
If u need more info, pls let me know.

Comment: I don't want to use listView for domain suggestions. Instead, I want inline suggestions for domain names.

Comment: Use setHint()? I think maybe that's a way to do it.